# php login page sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have created a register page which works perfectly fine, the information is inserted into the mysql, however when i want to login, it does not direct me to account.php for some reason. It says "Redirecting to: account.php can someone please help me with the code. I have put the whats in login.php and account.php

Thanks

**login.php**

```
$submitted_username = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 

    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id,
            forename,
            surname,
            Studentid, 
            username,
            salt, 
            password, 

            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

     $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

  not. 
     switch it to true. 
    $login_ok = false; 



    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) 
    { 

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

        if($check_password === $row['password']) 
        { 

            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    } 

 members-only page 
    //  again 
    if($login_ok) 
    { 

        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 


        $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

        // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
        header("Location: account.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to: account.php"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 

        print("Login Failed."); 


        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    } 
}
```

**account.php**

```
<?php 
    require("common.php"); 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        header("Location: Login.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to Login.php"); 
    } 
?> 

Hello <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>, secret content!<br /> 
<a href="edit_account.php">Edit Account</a><br /> 
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Take out the `die("Redirecting to Login.php");` and the look at your html source code for any possible white space, characters, etc. See anything?

Answer (score 0):

First know what is `die()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

You might want to use JavaScript redirect to do that since you want to display a message.

Put a JS on you page with a redirect script in `set_timeout()` of 3 seconds or what ever you want.

Comment: If you run a pure `header("Location: Login.php"); 

die("Redirecting to Login.php");` it works. So the problem here isn't the `header` or `die("message")` code. I admit the failures of a header("Location:") are frustrating, but javascript redirect or meta refresh is a cop out. Of course, they work when all else fails.